# Validation of different inputs

Tags: jquery, validation

i want to validate different inputs in my code but the error message appears for every input.

```
        $.each($('.input'), function(){
            if ($('.input').val() == "")
            $(this).css('border' , 'solid red');
            $(this).after('<span class="error">Name fehlt</span>');
            $(this).focus()


        })
```

`

Comment: What error message fdo you get?

Comment: If you have several inputs to validate, you may want to turn it into a function that takes the input element and an error message as parameters - if you only have the name to validate, you shouldn't use "each"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things here. `.each` works on a selector anyway so you can just do:

```
$(".input").each(...)
```

Second (and this is the reason your message is always appearing) your `if` statement is missing braces so it will only apply to the next statement: `$(this).css('border' , 'solid red');`

Finally, you can chain jQuery calls together:

```
$(".input").each(function() { // Nicer syntax
    // Refer to $(this) to get the value of the CURRENT input
    if($(this).val() == "") { // Don't forget your braces
        $(this).css("border", "solid red")
               // Method chaining
               .after('<span class="error">Name fehlt</span>');
               .focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this:

```
$('.input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).css('border', 'solid red');
        $(this).after('<span class="error">Name fehlt</span>');
        $(this).focus()
    }
})
```

`$.each` also does the same for you. However I think the above is more readable. But that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Going on the guess that you have several input fields, maybe you want something like:

```
validateInput($('.input-name'), 'Name fehlt');

function validateInput(input,errormsg){
    if (input.val() == "") {
        input.css('border', 'solid red');
        input.after('<span class="error">'+errormsg+'</span>');
        input.focus()
    }
}
```

Which means when you need to check another, you could do something like:

```
validateInput($('.input-street'),'Strasse fehlt');
```

Maybe an improvement even further would be to move the error-message to a data-attribute on the input field:

```
<input type="text" data-required-message="Name fehlt" class="input-name" />
```

so you could make it even more generic (and clean by getting content out of your Javascript) by getting it with something like

```
$(this).data('required-message')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `flags` in your `each` loop:

```
var isValid = true;
$(".input").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() === '' && isValid) {
        $this.css('border', 'solid red')
             .after('<span class="error">Name fehlt</span>')
             .focus();

        isValid = false;
        return false;
    }
});
return isValid;
```